# White screen when opening React Native from existing android app

Tags: android, performance, react-native

In Android, integrating react native to an existing app. Basically my android app was originally developed in java. From the java side, I click on button to go to another screen that is using React Native.

Then, there is a problem, every time I click the button that opens the RN activity/view controller, it takes 2 or 3 seconds in a white screen (loading the bundle).

Using react-native version:

```
"react-native": "0.45.1",
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
```

However, I tried a production build then white screen flash is little less, it's still takes 3 seconds in a white screen.

> In IOS, this fraction of time is very less and does not noticeable. So
>   it functions perfectly.

**Is there any way to pre load this bundle and avoid this white screen ?**

Comment: What inside render() functions of your new screen? Did it load data from storage or the Internet?

Comment: @GeniusQ I am loading data from internet but first white screen takes  2 or 3 seconds to display progress loader which is fetching data from internet.